# ASP.Net MVC kendo File Upload validations not working

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-upload

I have a simple Kendo MVC File Upload control. I want to restrict the file size and file type. Please find my code below:

```
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Upload()
        .Name("files123")
        .Async(a => a
            .Save("Save", "Upload")
            .Remove("Remove", "Upload")
            .SaveField("files")
        )
        .Validation(validation => validation.AllowedExtensions(new string[] { ".pdf" }))
    )
</div>
```

When I select an invalid format, it goes to the controller and the validation never gets fired.

I have spent considerable amount of time on this and could not find out any thing as nothing is happening.

Any inputs would be really helpful.

Comment: Are you referencing the latest .js files?

Comment: @ataravati.you got it right . Sorry for late response. I found that validations for kendo upload  is a new feature but the js files which were are referring does not that. I am going to replace kendo js files with latest files and then check.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo Upload validation is added after Kendo R3, 2016 release.

Here is the link: 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/controls/editors/upload/validation